# Which XML parser to use for this data?

Tags: xml, perl

I have XML data that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <account var1="" email="" firstname="" />
  <account email="" firstname="" />
  <account var1="" email="" firstname="" />
</root>
```

What XML parser for Perl would be recommended for this?

I use Linux, if that makes a difference.

Comment: It largely depends on what you need to do with the data.

Comment: What are your constraints and requirements from a parser?

Comment: For each row in the XML file would I like to output something like `var1, email, firstname`. So it would be great if I could get a $var1, $email, and $firstname for each row in the XML file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`XML::Simple` would be a good start if parsing isn't that complicated and you don't need a full DOM parser

Comment: Cool. What is a full DOM parser?

Comment: For the love of FSM, why are you even talking about that… thing from when Perl 5.6.0 roamed the earth? Recommend [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML) instead.

Comment: DOM is the Document Object Model. It is a method of representing and accessing the elements and attributes of XML data. A "full" DOM parser here probably  means that you do not need to modify your xml document (e.g inject/write back modified new content and save as xml). I think XML::Simple can do that too, but there are other libraries who can do it even  better. For just creating an in-memory perl data structure you can use XML::Simple.

Comment: @knb: +1 I couldn't have said it any better